# Подключение библиотеки в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, jar, библиотеки

Нашел библиотеку на GitHub https://github.com/processing/processing-sound
но не понимаю как подключить без jar файла, Maven не использую.

Comment: 1. Начать использовать `maven` или `gradle`. 2. склонить себе проект и скомпилировать его. 3. склонить себе и просто скопировать код проекта себе в проект (не советую делать, ровно как и не советую 2 пункт)

Comment: @Tsyklop, например я сделаю через maven, но что мне писать в файл pom, я не видел в гите ссылку на maven.

Comment: Для подключение любого проекта с гитхаба можно использовать репозиторий jitpack.io или подобные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как собрать написано в пункте **How to build** по приведенной ссылке проекта.

Там же на странице проекта, есть ссылка именуемая **Github releases page**, перейдя по ней выбираем нужную версию, качаем **sound.zip** файл, в нем есть jar'ники текущей sound библиотеки и еще двух (видимо внешних/вспомогательных/не знаю).

Затем добавляем библиотеку(-и) в свой проект - **File** -- **Project structure** -- **Project settings** -- **Libraries**, нажимаем **+** и выбираем библиотеки из файловой системы.

Comment: Да, спасибо за ответ, не додумался, что все ссылки будут там